# Can't update the second front end

Tags: drush, updating

I tried to run drush up on two front-ends (sharing a common database server). The first server went right and updated Drupal and modules just fine. But when I tried to run the same command on the second front end I just got:

```
Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will   [error]
need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
this command.
```

Yes, I am on the same directory on both servers. And yes, the SITE works on the second front end (checked with change to hosts) so it surely gets connection to the database server.

If I run drush status the outputs are same EXCEPT FOR missing "Drupal bootstrap: Successful" and lines for Drupal user and two Theme lines missing. So any ideas how to start resolving this problem?

hank

Answer (score 3):

Drush uses the database to determine what versions of modules are installed; therefore, Drush believes the second frontend to be up-to-date, even though the code is still at an older version.

To update your site:

- Do not update live. Make a local dev environment by copying one of the frontends and the database.  Update the local dev environment
- After updating and testing the local system, push the new code to the live systems.
- Run `drush updatedb` on both frontends